# How do I get the database primary key from a TMS TPlannerItem?

Tags: delphi, tms

In the TMS TDBPlanner OnDragDropItem event the PlannerItem references the item you dropped onto.
From this how do I get the primary key for the database row, so that I can updated related rows in my database?

Answer (score 1):

I found it. The TPlannerItem as a DBKey property. So I get it like this;

```
procedure TForm1.DBPlanner1DragDropItem(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
    PlannerItem: TPlannerItem);
var
  pk: integer;
begin
  inherited;

  pk := StrToInt(PlannerItem.DBKey);

end;
```